# WPF TreeView/TreeViewItem with TextBlock/Hyperlink crashes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

First example can be navigated with the keyboard *(arrow keys up and down)*.

```
<TreeView BorderThickness="0">
    <TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem.Header>
            <TextBlock>Parent</TextBlock>
        </TreeViewItem.Header>
        <TreeViewItem.Items>
            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock>Child</TextBlock>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem.Items>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Second contains a hyperlink and keyboard navigation crashes *(arrow keys up and down)*.

```
<TreeView BorderThickness="0">
    <TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem.Header>
            <TextBlock>Parent</TextBlock>
        </TreeViewItem.Header>
        <TreeViewItem.Items>
            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Hyperlink>
                            Child
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem.Items>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

> What am I doing wrong or what am I missing considering I'm quite new to `WPF/XAML`? Using `VS 2015.1` and `.NET 4.6`.

**Exception is:**

*`System.InvalidOperationException: 'System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink' is not a Visual or Visual3D.`*

```
at MS.Internal.Media.VisualTreeUtils.AsVisual(DependencyObject element, Visual&amp; amp; visual, Visual3D&amp;amp; visual3D)
at System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(DependencyObject reference)
at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.AllowHandleKeyEvent(FocusNavigationDirection direction)
at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.HandleUpDownKey(Boolean up, KeyEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(MSG&amp; amp; msg, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(MSG&amp; amp; msg, ModifierKeys modifiers)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(Object param)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(MSG&amp; amp; msg, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(MSG&amp; amp; msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
```

Added a bug report on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2093328). Who knows...

Comment: Does it crash, or does it throw an exception?  If so, what is the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including the message, traceback, and inner exception(s), if any?

Comment: @dbc Added exception here.

Comment: This seems to be a well know bug. See this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5982cafe-f75b-42b4-99dc-50d3a81b30b0/invalidoperationexception-systemwindowsdocumentshyperlink-is-not-a-visual-or-visual3d?forum=wpf) . Maybe setting `Focusable="False"` is an option for you.

Comment: @Dave That thread is from 2008... WTF... I mean WPF. Just my kind of luck. :) Thanks!